# Debussy as term for bathroom?

Tags: nouns, books

In Michael Bishop's SF book *Transfigurations* (1979), the author (in the course of the narration by the main character) refers in several instances to one or another "debussy", by which he evidently means a bathroom (i.e. a loo/WC/toilet/washroom, depending on your local usage).

I've never encountered this elsewhere and searching has turned up nothing. Is this an invented usage of the author's, or is there some precedent somewhere?

Comment: I'll thank users for refraining from edits that change the meaning of the question (and from editorializing on which country has a more "absurd" term). In the book, it referred to an indoor room that included a shower stall. Not, say, an outdoor trench.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

"Debussy" is a phonetic representation of pronouncing "WC," not to be mistaken for the classical composer Claude Debussy.  Basically, the author's employing an [eye dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect) to show how the character pronounces--or mispronounces--the letter W (double u) in WC.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99246/discussion-on-answer-by-user361733-debussy-as-term-for-bathroom).